# Value Controlled Colour Opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a TreeMap layout and was wondering how i could possibly control the opacity of the children rectangles depending on their values? But ideally, i would like each child to have specific fill, so that the audience will be able to visually see what city has a higher percentage of cancer patients than another city, rather than creating a legend myself. Currently, the entire TreeMap is set to one colour.

Sorry in advance for directly inputting the data in the code, i'm still learning the basics.

Cheers

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>TreeMap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="1200" height="720">
    <g></g>
    <section class="container1">
      <p class="p1"> North England </p><p class="p2"> South England </p>
      <p class="p3"> Bradford City </p><p class="p4"> Leeds </p>
      <p class="p5"> Liverpool </p><p class="p6"> Manchester </p>
      <p class="p7"> Sheffield </p><p class="p8"> Brighton </p>
      <p class="p9"> Bristol </p><p class="p10"> Luton </p>
      <p class="p11"> Milton Keynes </p><p class="p12"> Southampton </p>
      <object class="Box" class="cancer"></object>
    </section>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
var data = {
  "name": "England",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "North England",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Bradford City",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
        "name": "Leeds",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.52,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.29,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.71,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.82,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Liverpool",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 5.90,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.71,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.70,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.88,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Manchester",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.78,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 2.95,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.61,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.05,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Sheffield",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.54,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 4.57,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.85,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.08,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "South England",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Brighton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Bristol",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Luton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Milton Keynes",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color":"#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Southampton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([1000, 600])
  .paddingTop(20)
  .paddingInner(8);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

rootNode.sum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

treemapLayout(rootNode);

var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'})

  nodes
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
    .attr('opacity', function(d) { return 0.8 /* has to be like d.value / max or so */ })
    .attr('fill', function(d) { if (d.data.color) {
                                  return d.data.color
                                } else {
                                  return "white"
                                }})
  nodes
    .append('text')
    .attr('dx', 10)
    .attr('dy', 8)
        .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.value;
  });


  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply specify an opacity attribute like e.g. width or height. Just return a function and decide how to map your values into the percentage range (actually therefor you need to know your occurring maximum value).

> .attr('opacity', function(d) { return d.value / 10 })

In your code this would mean something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>Pack layout (with labels)</title>
</head>

<style>
rect {
  stroke: white;
}
text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  fill: black;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-anchor: end;
}


svg {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
</style>

<body>
  <svg width="1020" height="720">
    <g></g>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
var data = {
  "name": "North England",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Bradford City",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Cancer",
          "value": 1.18,
          "color": "red",
        },
        {
          "name": "CKD",
          "value": 3.21,
          "color": "green",
        },
        {
          "name": "CHD",
          "value": 2.57,
          "color": "blue",
        },
        {
          "name": "Diabetes",
          "value": 11.92,
          "color": "yellow",
        },
        {
          "name": "Strokes",
          "value": 1.18,
          "color": "gray",
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
};

var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([600, 400])
  .paddingOuter(20);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

rootNode.sum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

treemapLayout(rootNode);

var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'})

  nodes
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
    .attr('opacity', function(d) { return 0.5 /* has to be like d.value / max or so */ })
    .attr('fill', function(d) { if (d.data.color) { 
                                  return d.data.color 
                                } else {
                                  return "white"
                                }})

  nodes
    .append('text')
    .attr('dx', 4)
    .attr('dy', 14)
  .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
  });
  

  </script>
</body>
```

Updated:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>TreeMap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="1200" height="720">
    <g></g>
    <section class="container1">
      <p class="p1"> North England </p><p class="p2"> South England </p>
      <p class="p3"> Bradford City </p><p class="p4"> Leeds </p>
      <p class="p5"> Liverpool </p><p class="p6"> Manchester </p>
      <p class="p7"> Sheffield </p><p class="p8"> Brighton </p>
      <p class="p9"> Bristol </p><p class="p10"> Luton </p>
      <p class="p11"> Milton Keynes </p><p class="p12"> Southampton </p>
      <object class="Box" class="cancer"></object>
    </section>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
var data = {
  "name": "England",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "North England",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Bradford City",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
        "name": "Leeds",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.52,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.29,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.71,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.82,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Liverpool",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 5.90,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.71,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.70,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.88,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Manchester",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.78,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 2.95,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.61,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.05,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Sheffield",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.54,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 4.57,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.85,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.08,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "South England",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Brighton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Bristol",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Luton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Milton Keynes",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color":"#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Southampton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var maxValues = {
                "Cancer": 2.54,
                "CKD": 5.9,
                "CHD": 3.85,
                "Diabetes": 12,
                "Stroke": 2.13,
                }

var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([1000, 600])
  .paddingTop(20)
  .paddingInner(8);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

rootNode.sum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

treemapLayout(rootNode);

var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'})

  nodes
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
    .attr('opacity', function(d) { return d.value / maxValues[d.data.name] })
    .attr('fill', function(d) { if (d.data.color) {
                                  return d.data.color
                                } else {
                                  return "white"
                                }})
  nodes
    .append('text')
    .attr('dx', 10)
    .attr('dy', 8)
        .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.value;
  });


  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Cheers man, that works regarding the opacity. But how i can get an independent fill for each child? For example, cancer to coded to red, diabetes to be coded blue, etc. Then have the opacity reflect it's values?

Comment: You can define a color for each children in your dataset. And then dynamically set the color by using the same approach as for opacity. Have a look at the updated code snippet.

Comment: Hey mate, i've been playing around with your suggestion for value controlled opacity, but it doesn't seem to work (i aiming for stronger opacity with a higher valuer, etc) :/ I've updated my code in the description.

Comment: And what exactly does not work? Please be a little bit more explicit.

Comment: Controlling the opacity works, which is great, but it's for every value. What i would like is for the opacity to be independent for each disease. So if one city has a high cancer rate, the opacity is lighter, whereas if they have low cancer rate, the opacity is stronger. Because currently, the opacity is grouping every value in the dataset... So cancer values are being compared with diabetes values, etc, rather than an independent opacity for each disease. Sorry if this explanation isn't great.

Comment: You can store your maximum values for each disease in a separate variable. Then your opacity calculation for a specific disease will be compared to the same disease in the other districts. Have a look at the updated snippet.